Не работает тег <video> в firefox
Я добавил на сайт вот такой код:
<video width="320" height="240" controls><source scr="Series/1sn/S1.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>

Пишет типа формат файла не поддерживается и MIME-типе не найдено. Я менял формат файла в mov, webm, avi единственное когда я поменял формат видео не выходила ошибка, но видео все равно не работает. Говорят обновить flash player обновил без результата. Менял браузер на chromium ничего, все также.
Еще говорил понять видео кодек на h264, но при этом не говорят как! Пожалуйста есть способ исправить это ?

добавь скриншот ошибки

Я менял формат файла - как именно? Просто менял расширение в названии файла?

У вас сервер запущен? Или вы просто в браузере открывате .html?

Что за ИИ сгенерировал этот вопрос?

ФЛЕШ ПЛЕЕР в 2024?  Я бы машину времени использовал более разумно. А по вопросу - хотя бы страницу с проблемой показал и рассказал как именно ты добавляешь код в ВП.

@Alexandr_TT, а откуда вёрдпресс взялся?

Поскольку адрес источника видео указан без начального слэша, то сервер пытается найти файл по относительному адресу. По-видимому, не находит и выдаёт стандартную страницу 404 ошибки. Эта страница имеет MIME-тип text/html, который, естественно не поддерживается <video>.

Попробуйте загрузить через iframe. у меня недавно тоже была ошибка, когда я грузил через html5, писал про flash не поддерживается.
Попробуйте написать так - <iframe src="/Series/1sn/S1.mp4" width="320" height="240"></iframe>
